# How to enter token without leaving history in terminal?

Tags: bash, git, curl, terminal, prompt

I'm trying to call GitHub API in the terminal. It requires to input the username and token. Token are entered with plain text. For security purposes, I don't feel like leaving some token history on this public computer.

How can I enter the token without leaving history?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `$HISTCONTROL` is set to `ignorespace` or `ignoreboth` (which is the default):

You can **type a space before the command** to prevent it from being recorded in the history.

See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/115922/198262

If you need to use this command several times, you can first store the token in a variable and prefix the variable assignment with a space and then just use the variable in your commands without having to remember the space. You could also disable the history for the current session entirely using `set +o history`.